# ddply: Why isn't this working?

Tags: r, plyr

I am very new working with R, but it seems like the following code should work. Why aren't I getting the stats I need? Thanks.

```
> stats <- ddply(Y, "SECT", summarise, mean.EE = mean(EE), 
+                                      sd.EE = sd(EE),
+                                      mean.AA = mean(AA),
+                                      sd.AA = sd(AA),
+                                      mean.II = mean(II),
+                                      sd.II = sd(II))
> stats
  SECT mean.EE sd.EE mean.AA sd.AA mean.II sd.II
1   H1      NA    NA      NA    NA      NA    NA
2   H2      NA    NA      NA    NA      NA    NA
3   H3      NA    NA      NA    NA      NA    NA
> str(Y)
'data.frame':   537 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ WORD: chr  "a" "a" "a" "a" ...
 $ SECT: chr  "H1" "H1" "H1" "H1" ...
 $ EE  : num  2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ AA  : num  1.38 1.38 1.38 1.38 1.38 ...
 $ II  : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

PS - I know it looks like each of the variables (EE, AA, II) have no variation, but that's just because they are sorted...

Comment: Try adding `na.rm = TRUE` to the mean functions.  If you have any `NA` in the variable, it turns everything to `NA`.

Comment: Is there any NA values in "EE". If that is the case, you can use `na.rm=TRUE`

Comment: Embarrassingly, this was the problem. I solved it by using ddply(na.omit(Y)...). is na.rm=TRUE more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

Also try using `dplyr`

```
# install.packages('dplyr')
library(dplyr)

meanna <- function(x) mean(x, na.rm = T)
sdna <- function(x) sd(x, na.rm = T)

Y %>%
  group_by(SECT) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(meanna, sdna), -WORD)
```